# Installation of ivisual module for Python 3.6 under Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I have installed ivisual package from PyPi and then in the directory of Anaconda I ran the command 'import ivisual'. CMD showed following message

```
>>> import ivisual
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ratangd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ivisual\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .visual import *
  File "C:\Users\ratangd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ivisual\visual.py", line 32, in <module>
    import ujson
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ujson'
```

After this I installed ujson module and then again tried `import ivisual`
Following message was displayed with Command line

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ratangd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ivisual\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .visual import *
  File "C:\Users\ratangd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ivisual\visual.py", line 562, in <module>
    get_ipython().kernel.comm_manager.register_target('glow', GlowWidget)
AttributeError: 'InteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'kernel'
In :
```

How to resolve this problem, as I want to use this `import ivisual` without any problem for Vpython related code?

Comment: It's possible this is only supported in Jupyter Notebooks, not in the command line. Can you try in a Notebooik?

Answer (score 0):

ivisual was an experiment that led to the vpython module, which is the currently maintained version. See the first page of vpython.org.

For VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users